# Unable to enter pose mode

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

I'm new to Blender and have been following a video series on Udemy about this software. I'm in the section where we learn how to model and animate a lamp. In this section we've learned how to use pose mode. I was able to use pose mode in previous lectures before, but all of a sudden yesterday, pose mode seems to have disappeared from the drop-down menu in the top left corner. I don't know why it's vanished or how to bring it back, does anyone know how I can solve this issue? Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: You don't use pose mode on meshes or curves. Pose mode is used exclusively on armatures. Select an armature and the menu will appear then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop-down menu (top left) is context-sensitive. Select your `Armature` in the Outliner (on the right side). This will bring back the Pose Mode.

Comment: Ok it works now thank you! :)